# WiFi router that lets me disable WiFi based on schedule

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, scheduled-tasks

I have that Fritz!Box 7390 that has the setting to disable WiFi based on a schedule. So, it's off from 11 PM to 6 AM while we're sleeping.

Now, I want to extend the network with another WiFi router. Criteria are:

- Gigabit ethernet ports (4 preferred)
- 11n WiFi (that could be disabled based on a schedule)
- WiFi could be disabled based on a schedule
- affordable

I looked at the TP-Link TL-WR1043ND (http://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/TL-WR1043ND/index.htm) that has

- 4 Gigabit ethernet ports ✓
- 11n WiFi ✓
- affordable price ✓

but unfortunately doesn't seem to have

- **WiFi could be disabled based on a schedule ✗**

Are there any competitors that could provide me that feature?

Comment: If the wired network is allowed to go down too, you could consider just getting a timer for a wall outlet and let it switch the router off on a schedule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into routers that can run [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database). You can schedule wifi using cron as documented in this [blog post](http://markspizz.net/?p=389). Looks like [TomatoUSB supports](http://tomatousb.org/forum/t-276506/enabled-disable-wifi-on-a-timer) this as well.

You best bet will be to use an open-source firmware on supported hardware.

Comment: Looks promising. Since the dd-wrt could be run on the TL-WR1043ND, I just ordered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending the wireless network with another wifi router, then surely this other router will automatically not give out wifi, as the Fritz stops giving out Wifi? It will just reconnect when the schedule kicks in. No need to schedule both routers unless it's RF you are worried about. I would personally just use a timer switch on the AC adapter.

Comment: This is not going to work since I'm using a LAN connection between the router and the Fritz and the router simply creates an own network with the same SSID/credentials as the Fritz does. And just using a timer switch is also no option since the LAN part of the router shall be active 24/7 so that my TV could update over LAN. Should have mentioned that in my question...

Comment: Schedule that the fritz only allows the other router internet access at the times you require. The other router will stay on, broadcasting but you won't be able to join as the fritz won't give it access.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH, it will fulfill your hardware requests. Then I would load [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) onto it.  This is my current setup.  You can schedule your wireless and many more things in this router.